# Wrong YAML indent in PhpStorm - .editorconf

Tags: yaml, phpstorm, editorconfig

I am currently struggling that my PhpStorm is intending `.yaml` sequences which have other properties than just a string. E.g. in the picture with keys in an sequence.

[image]

The desired behaviour is to have autoformatting which complies with the project - the old values in the git change picture.

The `.editorconf` is basic and does not handle this. The PhpStorm `.yaml` formatting properties are the default properties. Tested every option but nothing led to the desired result.

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

[*.yaml]
quote_type = single
```

Is there a `.editorconf` property which leads to the correct formatting?

Comment: What is the full name of your YAML file?

Comment: `organisation-admin-news.yaml` - it contains OA3

Comment: You have a global rule in your `.editorconf` with `indent_size = 4` and it applies to `.yaml` files as well. You can change it to 2 (or set it to 2 for yaml files) or delete it from a global pattern entirely.

Comment: the indent of 4 spaces is desired in the yaml file - however within a sequence item a indent between the dash and the key is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a `.editorconf` property which leads to the correct formatting?

No, your use-case is too exotic. You are basically saying „Have 4 spaces between indentation levels but not in specific contexts, that are to be recognised by taking the semantics of the file into account“. Also, it would be unclear how to continue at such a level:

```yaml
foo:
    - one: two
      three:
        lorem
      four:
          ipsum
      five:
            dolor
six:
    seven:
        eight
```

In this example, `lorem`'s indentation is at the next proper indentation level (2*4 spaces). That looks very strange.

`ipsum` is *relatively* indented, i.e. not at a proper indentation level (2*4 + 2 spaces) but 4 spaces more than the previous level. That is very irregular as you can see by comparing with `eight` further down below, which does not have sequences in between and is therefore on a proper indentation level.

`dolor` is at the proper indentation level according to its depth (depth 3, therefore 3*4 indentation spaces). This makes sense if you only want to take two indentation spaces away from items directly in a sequence, but again looks very strange.

Whichever solution you are after, it is quite obvious that the simple idea of „fixed number of spaces per indentation level“ is not applicable to it. Therefore, the basic indentation capability of an editor does not suffice to implement it. I do not know an editor that supports even one of the cases I described.